# Call middleware only once for multiple routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, express-router

I have an api for an dashboard and it has routes like this

```
/dashboardRoutes/getdata1
/dashboardRoutes/getdata2
.
.
.
/dashboardRoutes/getdata7
```

in backend i am using express router.use to divert them to a handler.

```
router.use('/dashboardRoutes',getHirarchiEmp,dashboardRoutesHandler)
```

```
#dashboardRoutesHandler

/getdata1,handler1()
/getdata2,handler2()
.
.
.
/getdata7,handler7()
```

this router has a middleware getHirarchiEmp which attaches data to req body which i am going to use in individual handlers, now this middleware is getting called on every route as i have 7 routes it is getting called 7 times. Is there any way i can call the middleware only once and the data is also availbe in all handlers

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot spawn two middlewares at a time.
***'Express Middleware'*** is just a fancy way of chaining a bunch of functions. One thing to note is that middlewares are ordered.

In Express, you can set up middleware to be “global” middleware; meaning it will be called for every incoming request.

[Click to preview image](https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/a22bb45df146d43b57f2f6c90182d19e7394cd96/d6e10/assets-jekyll/blog/express-middleware-examples/middleware-30b3b30ad54e21d8281719042860f3edd9fb1f40f93150233a08165d908f4631.png)

**Middleware Order is Important**, when a request is received by Express, each middleware that matches the request is run in the order it is initialized until there is a terminating action (like a response being sent). So if an error occurs, all middleware that is meant to handle errors will be called in order until one of them does not call the next() function call.